# How to create external table on parquet file

Tags: hive, parquet

I have a parquet file on gcp storage. File converted from simple json {"id":1,"name":"John"}.

Could you help me write the correct script? Is it possible to do that without schema?

```
create external table test (
    id         string,
    name       string
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\;'
stored as ?????
location '??????'
tblproperties ('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive is , as sql databases, working in a write-in schema architecture so you cannot create a table using HQL without using a schema ( not like other cases for NoSql like Hbase for example or others). I advise you to use a Hive version >= 0.14, it is easier:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    string1 string,
    string2 string,
    int1 int,
    boolean1 boolean,
    long1 bigint,
    float1 float,
    double1 double,
    inner_record1 struct,
    enum1 string,
    array1 array,
    map1 map,
    union1 uniontype,
    fixed1 binary,
    null1 void,
    unionnullint int,
    bytes1 binary)
  PARTITIONED BY (ds string);
```

Comment: Ok, thank u for advice. Could you show the script or send a link, how to do that with Hive version >= 0.14

Comment: The example in the response is for a hive version>= .14 , did you try it ?

Comment: can't understand how it works, example does not have location to parquet files

Comment: Just add in the end of the query, the columns name should have the same names as in parquet   :  STORED AS PARQUET
    LOCATION  '/path/to/parquet';